# Core data: renaming a property while fetching

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have two entities with below relationship:

```
Contact <--> ContactMeta
```

Here, Contact has one of the relationships as 'contactMeta' and ContactMeta has one of the attributes as 'operation'.

I am firing a fetchRequest on Contact entity. The result type is NSDictionaryResultType.

So I am getting an array of dictionaries, which I am serializing using NSJSONSerialization and sending as JSON request to server.

Now, I am adding "contactMeta.operation" to propertiesToFetch list, so one of the keys in dictionary is "contactMeta.operation".

**Problem is-** I need to send "operation" as key, in place of "contactMeta.operation", in JSON request.

**I have one option-** to iterate through each dictionary in the list, adding a key- "operation" with value as value for key "contactMeta.operation", and then removing the key-value for "contactMeta.operation".

But I am not satisfied with this approach and was thinking that in sqlite we can have a query like this:

```
Select first_name, last_name, contactmeta as operation from contact;
```

Can we do similar stuff in core data or is there any smart and better way to implement what I am trying to do?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hunch was right, there is another way. NSExpressionDescription is what you are looking for.

```
    NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contact"];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"contactmeta"];
    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setName:@"operation"];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:keyPathExpression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSUndefinedAttributeType];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"first_name",@"last_name",expressionDescription]];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* rez = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: voila... exactly what I needed :-)

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me, even today I refer this answer to implement similar requirements, so I am rewarding it with some of the points which I earned :)